# Enabling CORS for nodejs in gcloud app engine

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

i need to host a express server in gcp app engine as an api server, everything works fine except CORS. i had used the node cors module and it worked fine in my local machine. but when i deployed the service in app engine the same cors issue is again came.
i had tried many thing with the app.yaml file but i am not an expert in it.

```
runtime: nodejs16

instance_class: F2

env_variables:
  MY_secret:"secret"

handlers:
  - url: /stylesheets
    static_dir: stylesheets

  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto
```

i got this code from online, can someone help me here to fix this issue.
i need the entire app to be CORS enabeled.

here is the request from the browser

```
var settings = {
  url: `example.com.com/register/details`,
  method: "POST",
  timeout: 0,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    id: id,
  }),
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
...do something...
}
```

i had used the CORS module in node

```
var whitelist = ["foo.com", "foo2.com"];
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
    }
  },
};

app.use("/register", cors(corsOptions), registerRoutes);
```

and also the issue is only for some routes.
rest everything works fine

the error am getting is

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.sambhram.com/register/details' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: The first step is to add details on a) the request that generates an error b) the error details. CORS is enforced in the browser and not your backend service. Your backend service must respond with the correct headers. What are the CORS headers being returned? Using the CLI **curl** can also help with debugging CORS issues.

Comment: updated the question with more details!

Comment: Yes, you provided more details but not the details required. Revisit my comment on what is required to debug this. Another question, is this URL your domain or a cross origin request? http://api.sambhram.com/register/details If it is your domain, add the correct CORS headers to your server. If it is not your domain, then you will need to ask the admin of that domain to allow your domain to make requests.

Comment: Please, read this article about [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your post accordingly.

Comment: the domain is mine only, can you please tell me which and all headers should be added for this requests. am not an expert in this. please help me here because its really urgent and we are running out of tiime.

Comment: Your error shows you're trying to access a remote resource from your local server ```http://127.0.0.1```. Did you add your local server to your White List? Another option is to set Origin to ```*``` which means to allow any origin